# Calling fftw routines from pure subroutines in Fortran90

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, fortran90, fftw

Multithreaded FFTW can be implemented as in [this](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Usage-of-Multi_002dthreaded-FFTW.html) from FFTW homepage. Instead, we want to call the serial FFTW routines within `OpenMP` parallel environment using multiple threads. We want `variable` and `fourier_variable` to be thread-safe. This could be done by using `PURE` subroutines and declaring `variable` and `fourier_variable` inside it. The question here is related to calling FFTW routines like `fftw_execute_dft_r2c` from within a `PURE` subroutine.

A stripped-down version of the code is presented here just for reference (the full code is an optimisation solver involving many FFTW calls).

```
PROGRAM main
USE fft_call
REAL(8), DIMENSION(1:N, 1:N) :: variable
COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), DIMENSION(1:N/2+1, 1:N) :: fourier_variable
INTEGER :: JJ

!$OMP PARALLEL
!$OMP DO 
 DO JJ = 1, 5
   call fourier_to_physical(fourier_variable, variable)
 END DO
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
END PROGRAM main


MODULE fft_call

contains
PURE SUBROUTINE fourier_to_physical( fourier_variable, variable)
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(8), DIMENSION(1:N, 1:N) :: variable
COMPLEX(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), DIMENSION(1:N/2+1, 1:N), INTENT(OUT) :: fourier_variable
    CALL fftw_execute_dft_r2c (plan_fwd, variable, fourier_variable)
END SUBROUTINE fourier_to_physical

END MODULE fft_call
```

The error while calling `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d` from the `PURE` subroutine `fourier_to_physical`:

`Error: Function reference to 'fftw_plan_dft_r2c' at (1) is to a non-PURE procedure within a PURE procedure`

The question: is there a way to call FFTW routines like `fftw_execute_dft_r2c` from within a `PURE` subroutine in Fortran90?

Or, in other words, are their `PURE` versions of `fftw_execute_dft_r2c` such that we can call them from `PURE` procedures? We are beginners to `OpenMP`.

Comment: No. FFTW routines are not pure (in the Fortran sense) so can not be called from a pure Fortran subprogram. But why do you need pure? I can't see anything in what you are doing that requires it. Oh, and please don't use the non-portable Real(8), see any number of questions here which discuss that.

Comment: As already mentioned above, we need `variable` and `fourier_variable` to be thread-safe.

Comment: Thread safety does not require  called routines to be pure. I agree it is very nice to do so, but the use of pure is severely limited by use of external libraries such as FFTW, BLAS or MPI, few of which provide the appropriate pure interfaces. Thus in practice more often than not you just have to forget pure.  If properly ceded you don't need to declare the routine pure to make it work.

Comment: Thanks. We will work on improving our knowledge about thread-safety.